# I want to show info window when I click on google map marker in ReactJS App?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I used infoWindow but when I click on marker, no infoWindow shows. How it will be shown by clicking the marker? I am getting the markers from props. Markers shown on map but these are not clickable. If I call a function on Click and show alert box, then all the data shows in the alert box. But I only want to open infoWindow on marker click.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'google-maps-react';
import logo from '../assests/fbicon.png'

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '50%'
};

class LiveLocation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lati: "",
      long: "",
      isOpen: false,
      showingInfoWindow: false,  
      activeMarker: {},         
      selectedPlace: {},       
      markerMap: "",
      selectedPlace: ""
    };
  }

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });

  onClose = props => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      });
    }
  }
  handleToggleOpen = () => {

    this.setState({
      isOpen: true
    });
  }

  handleToggleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false
    });
  }

  displayMarkers = () => {
    console.log(this.props.store)
    return this.props.store.map((stores, index) => {
      console.log(stores._id)
      return (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          position={{ lat: stores.lat, lng: stores.lng }}
          label={index}
          onClick={() => this.handleToggleOpen()}
          icon={{url:logo,scaledSize:new window.google.maps.Size(40,40)}}
        >

          {
            this.state.isOpen && 
            <InfoWindow  onCloseClick={this.onClose}>
              <span>Something</span>
            </InfoWindow>
          }

        </Marker>
      );
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.setState({
        lati: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude
      });
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log(this.props)}
        <div>
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={10}
            style={mapStyles}
            initialCenter={{
              lat: this.props.lati,
              lng: this.props.long

            }}
          >
            {this.displayMarkers()}
          </Map>

        </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I noticed in the code you provided,

1. You set your initialCenter to the `this.props.lati and this.props.long` however I noticed that you are getting the location  of the user in the componentDidMount where you set the state of `lati` and `long`. Do you have lati and long variable in your props or do you mean to use the lati and long from the state? If so,you need to use the `this.state.lati or this.state.long`. The value of your state is empty and it will default the initialCenter to (0,0). If you want it to center at the user location use `center` parameter instead of `initialCenter`.
2. In your onClick in Marker object, you need to call the `{this.onMarkerClick}` function and you can remove the `handleToggleOpen` and `handleToggleClose` function. You can also remove these in your state:

```
   isOpen: false,
   markerMap: "",
   selectedPlace: ""
```

3. In your label parameter in the Marker, you are passing {index} and the datatype of this is not a string. labels need strings for it to work. You can make it {index.toString()}.
4. To show the InfoWindow, you don't need to append it inside the  object in your displayMarkers function. Put it after you call `{this.displayMarkers()}` in your Map object.

You can check this [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/infowindow-tndjvx?file=Map.js) and code snippet I made to achieve your use case. Note that I used sample props value and just use a props value for the center of the map. The rest, I derived from your code. To make the code work, you need to put your API key.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker, InfoWindow } from 'google-maps-react';

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '50%'
};

class LiveLocation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      lati: this.props.center.lat,
      long: this.props.center.lng,
      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {}
    };
  }

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) =>
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });

  onInfoWindowClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: null,
      showingInfoWindow: false
    });
  };
  



  displayMarkers = () => {
    return this.props.store.map((stores, index) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          key={index}
          position={{ lat: stores.lat, lng: stores.lng }}
          label={index.toString()}
          name={stores.id}
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          //icon={{url:logo,scaledSize:new window.google.maps.Size(40,40)}}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({
        lati: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={14}
            style={mapStyles}
            initialCenter={{
              lat: this.state.lati,
              lng: this.state.long
            }}
          >
            {this.displayMarkers()}
            <InfoWindow
              marker={this.state.activeMarker}
              onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
              visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
            >
              <div>
                <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          </Map>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'YOUR_KEY'
})(LiveLocation);
```